# Web service workers and clearing browsing data

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push

I am currently working my way through the web push API and service workers. Since this whole API is pretty new I could not really find any info regarding what happens if users delete their browsing data.

When I tested this it looks like the service worker file is (obviously) removed and with it the whole registration for web push becomes invalid. So the user will create a new registration (automatically?) when visiting a page that he previously granted permission to, correct?

As for private browsing I presume any granted permission would only be valid in the context of that very browsing session and discarded afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

> So the user will create a new registration (automatically?) when visiting a page that he previously granted permission to, correct?

It depends on the browser and on the specific action performed by the user. If the user only removes the cache but does not reset the browser permission, then when you call `pushManager.subscribe()` the next time you will get a new endpoint directly and no prompt will be displayed to the user. On the other hand, if the user has also removed the permission, then `pushManager.subscribe()` will show the permission prompt again.

> As for private browsing I presume any granted permission would only be valid in the context of that very browsing session and discarded afterwards?

Some browsers return permission `denied` by default when browsing in private mode (no prompt is displayed to the user).

Comment: Got it, so for deleted cache in any case there would not be a way that the browser still has permission granted but service workers are not registering anymore when visiting the page?